# Не выполняется логика после нажатия кнопкки. PyQt5 - python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Создал окно в *QT Designer* и конвертировал в питон файл. 
Создал отдельный класс для создания логики, наследовал класс интерфейса.

Даю команду, по нажатии писать в чат **`1`**, но ничего не происходит.

Подскажите что я делаю не так.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(368, 182)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.project_name = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.project_name.setEnabled(True)
        self.project_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.project_name.setFont(font)
        self.project_name.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.project_name.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.project_name.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.project_name.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.project_name.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.project_name.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.project_name.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.project_name.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.project_name.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.project_name.setTabChangesFocus(False)
        self.project_name.setUndoRedoEnabled(True)
        self.project_name.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.project_name.setReadOnly(False)
        self.project_name.setOverwriteMode(False)
        self.project_name.setAcceptRichText(True)
        self.project_name.setObjectName("project_name")
        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_name.setFont(font)
        self.label_name.setObjectName("label_name")
        self.label_token = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_token.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_token.setFont(font)
        self.label_token.setObjectName("label_token")
        self.vk_token = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vk_token.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.vk_token.setFont(font)
        self.vk_token.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.vk_token.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.vk_token.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.vk_token.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.vk_token.setObjectName("vk_token")
        self.radio_group = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radio_group.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.radio_group.setFont(font)
        self.radio_group.setObjectName("radio_group")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 100, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.radioButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 351, 23))
        self.button_start.setObjectName("button_start")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setEnabled(False)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 368, 21))
        self.menubar.setDefaultUp(False)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаблон Чат-Бота ВК"))
        self.label_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя проекта"))
        self.label_token.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Токен"))
        self.radio_group.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Группа"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Аккаунт"))
        self.button_start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сделать шаблон бота"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.create_bot)
    def create_bot(self):
        print("1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все вы сделали правильно, только надо сделать экземпляр класса `MainWindow` и показать его:

```
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
```

---

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(368, 182)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.project_name = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.project_name.setEnabled(True)
        self.project_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.project_name.setFont(font)
        self.project_name.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.project_name.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.project_name.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.project_name.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.project_name.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.project_name.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.project_name.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.project_name.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.project_name.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.project_name.setTabChangesFocus(False)
        self.project_name.setUndoRedoEnabled(True)
        self.project_name.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.project_name.setReadOnly(False)
        self.project_name.setOverwriteMode(False)
        self.project_name.setAcceptRichText(True)
        self.project_name.setObjectName("project_name")
        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_name.setFont(font)
        self.label_name.setObjectName("label_name")
        self.label_token = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_token.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_token.setFont(font)
        self.label_token.setObjectName("label_token")
        self.vk_token = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vk_token.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.vk_token.setFont(font)
        self.vk_token.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.vk_token.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.vk_token.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.vk_token.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.vk_token.setObjectName("vk_token")
        self.radio_group = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radio_group.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.radio_group.setFont(font)
        self.radio_group.setObjectName("radio_group")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 100, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.radioButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 351, 23))
        self.button_start.setObjectName("button_start")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setEnabled(False)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 368, 21))
        self.menubar.setDefaultUp(False)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаблон Чат-Бота ВК"))
        self.label_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя проекта"))
        self.label_token.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Токен"))
        self.radio_group.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Группа"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Аккаунт"))
        self.button_start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сделать шаблон бота"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.create_bot)
        
    def create_bot(self):
        print("1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть эта часть кода не нужна? #    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

Comment: @Dariuz да, не нужна. Вы ее делаете здесь - `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):` и здесь `self.setupUi(self)`

Answer (score 1):

Вы ведь не используете свой `MainWindow` в `if __name__ == "__main__":` должно быть:

```
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```